# Connect Excel to Netsuite Driver

Tags: excel, odbc, driver, netsuite

I am currently trying to connect the Netsuite ODBC to Excel. When I try to put in a query, I received the error:

Unable to connect. We encountered an error while trying to connect.

"ODBC: ERROR [42S02] [NetSuite][ODBC 64bit driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Base table:employee not found.[10129]"

I downloaded the 64 bit odbc driver and gave myself the correct role of "Data Warehouse Integrator".

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be caused by attempting to connect to a non-existent table ('employee').  According to the [NetSuite Connect Browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2021_1/odbc/record/employee.html) the table name for the Employee Record is 'Employees' (plural).

Answer (score 0):

The NS table name is `employee` `SELECT * FROM employee`.
To adjust the role for the accounting team I used this free tool from Tim Dietrich [SuitQL Query Tool](https://timdietrich.me/netsuite-suitescripts/suiteql-query-tool/). When you deploy the "suitelet" select "Execute As" your role `Data Warehouse Integrator`. And run the above query:

- If you have any result that means you have a connection/configuration issue.
- If you see `Search error occurred: Record 'employee' was not found.`, it's 100% a role access problem.

Comment: Thank you! I created a new role, copying the "Data Warehouse Integrator" permissions and connected it that way.